# Error 234 "More data is available" with GetComputerNameEx

Tags: c, string, winapi

I am getting `More data is available` error with the `GetComputerNameEx` function, but no idea how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
int wmain()
{
    COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT nameType = ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified;
    WCHAR computerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
    DWORD size = ARRAYSIZE(computerName);

    BOOL pcName = GetComputerNameEx(nameType, computerName, &size);

    DWORD error = GetLastError();



    if (pcName != 0)
    {
        wprintf("Computer name: %s\n", computerName);
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Error getting the name. Code: %li\n", error);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

No idea how to set `size` variable as output so I can declare the `computerName` array correctly.

Comment: [**ERROR_MORE_DATA**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724301(v=vs.85).aspx) -- 
*The lpBuffer buffer is too small. The lpnSize parameter contains the number of bytes required to receive the name.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the `GetComputerNameEx()` documentation:

> *lpBuffer* [out]
>   A pointer to a buffer that receives the computer name or the cluster virtual server name.
>
> **The length of the name may be greater than `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH` characters** because DNS allows longer names. To ensure that this buffer is large enough, set this parameter to `NULL` and use the required buffer size returned in the `lpnSize` parameter.
>
> *lpnSize* [in, out]
>   On input, specifies the size of the buffer, in `TCHAR`s. On output, receives the number of `TCHAR`s copied to the destination buffer, not including the terminating null character.
>
> **If the buffer is too small, the function fails and `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_MORE_DATA`**. This parameter receives the size of the buffer required, including the terminating null character.
>
> If `lpBuffer` is NULL, this parameter must be zero.

For example:

```
int wmain()
{
    COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT nameType = ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified;
    WCHAR *computerName = NULL, *computerNameNew;
    DWORD size = 0;
    BOOL pcName;
    DWORD error;

    do
    {
        pcName = GetComputerNameExW(nameType, computerName, &size);
        if (pcName) break;

        error = GetLastError();
        if (error != ERROR_MORE_DATA) break;

        computerNameNew = (WCHAR*) realloc(computerName, sizeof(WCHAR) * size);
        if (!computerNameNew) {
            error = ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
            break;
        }

        computerName = computerNameNew;
    }
    while (1);

    if (pcName)
    {
        wprintf("Computer name: %s\n", computerName);
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Error getting the name. Code: %ul\n", error);
    }

    free(computerName);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to call the function twice; once with a null pointer to get the required size, and again with a buffer of (at least) the specified size. As the docs say:

> To ensure that this buffer is large enough, set this parameter to NULL
>   and use the required buffer size returned in the lpnSize parameter.

This is a common pattern for Win32 functions. And yes, it does lead to a possible race condition, but that's just how it works.

**Example**

```
DWORD dwSize = 0;
if (GetComputerNameEx(nameType, nullptr, &dwSize))
{
    WCHAR* computerName;
    computerName = (WCHAR*)malloc(dwSize * sizeof(WCHAR));
    if (GetComputerNameEx(nameType, computerName, &dwSize))
    {
        // use the name
    }
    free(computerName); // don't forget to free
}
```

Comment: Note that the reason `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH` isn't working is because that's the maximum length for the *unqualified* name and the OP's code asks for the *qualified* name.  I'm not sure there's any fixed limit to the length of the full DNS name.

Comment: But I cannot set the `computerName[size]` after calling the `GetComputerNameEx` first time, because Visual Studio says `Expression must have a constant value`. What can I do? I did not use your actual code because I am using C.

Comment: Use `malloc/free` instead of `new/delete` then. I have updated the example.

Comment: I posted an answer with code that I think won't suffer from race condition.

Comment: FYI, when `GetComputerNameEx()` fails with `ERROR_MORE_DATA`, the value of `dwSize` already includes space for a null terminator, so you don't need `++dwSize`. This is documented behavior: "*If the buffer is too small, the function fails and `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_MORE_DATA`. This parameter receives the size of the buffer required, **including the terminating null character**.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes you're right. What a confusing function. Sometimes it includes it and sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

That error means that the `GetComputerNameEx` function needs a larger buffer to store the returned string.

To avoid the race condition cited in Jonathan Potter's answer, you could do something like this:

```
LONG error = ERROR_MORE_DATA;
WCHAR* buffer = NULL;
DWORD bufferLength = /* Some initial reasonable length for the string buffer */;
while (error == ERROR_MORE_DATA) {
    // Create a buffer with bufferLength size (measured in WCHARs)
    buffer = realloc(buffer, bufferLength * sizeof(WCHAR));

    if (GetComputerNameEx(nameType, buffer, &bufferLength)) {
        error = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    } else {
        error = GetLastError();
    }
}
if (error != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    // Some error occurred
    ...
}

// Use buffer containing computer name

// Don't forget to free(buffer)
```

Comment: if you are going to use `malloc()`, you could at least use `realloc()` instead of `free()` while looping.  Otherwise, consider using `LocalAlloc()`/`LocalReAlloc()` instead. Also, you need to use `GetLastError()` to get the `error` value, it is not returned by `GetComputerNameEx()` itself.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've updated the code. Anyway, one of the reasons I used `free`+`malloc` instead of `realloc` was that there's no need to preserve the previous memory content between reallocations.

Comment: True. On the other hand, depending on the memory manager implementation, `realloc()` may be able to simply expand the existing memory block without having to search for and reserve a whole new block elsewhere in memory.